# psfrag values not shown after compiling code

Tags: psfrag

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{epsfig,rotating,times,psfrag,pstricks,tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor,array,graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
  \small
  \psfrag{4}[c][c]{~~~4}
  \psfrag{5}[c][c]{5}
  \psfrag{6}[c][c]{6}
  \psfrag{7}[c][c]{7}
  \psfrag{8}[c][c]{8}
  \psfrag{9}[c][c]{9}
  \psfrag{10}[c][c]{10}
  \psfrag{11}[c][c]{11}
  \psfrag{12}[c][c]{12~~~}

  \centerline{\includegraphics[width=100mm]{PCR.eps}}

\begin{picture}(0,0)(0,0)
  \put(0, 217){~~~0}
  \put(0, 177){-10}
  \put(0, 135){-20}
  \put(0,  93){-30}
  \put(0,  51){-40}
  \put(0,11.5){-50}

  \put(58,  20){$\mathbf{R}_{\mathbf{yy}}$}
  \put(105, 20){$\mathbf{R}_{\mathbf{xx}}$}

  %\put(156.75, 23){\makebox(0,0)[ct]{\normalsize (b)}}
  \put(-12,  147){\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\begin{sideways}{\normalsize Reflection (dB)}\end{sideways}}}
  \put(159, -5){\makebox(0,0)[ct]{\normalsize Frequency (GHz)}}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \path (0,0) coordinate (origin);
  \draw[very thick, blue](1.2, 0.8)--++(.75,0);
  \draw[dash pattern={on 6pt off 2.5pt on 6pt off 2.5pt}, very thick, red](2.9, 0.8)--++(.75,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{picture}

\end{document}
```

When I compile this code I did not get the `psfrag` values on the axis. Can someone help ?

Comment: did you use latex dvips ps2pdf (not pdflatex) and did you get any errors

Comment: hello i use latex then dvips then use ps2pdf but still the same i did not get any thing on the x-axis

Comment: after compiling i did not get any error

Comment: impossible to say without seeing the eps but your replacements look a bit odd, psfrag assumes that the string that is being replaced only occurs once but you are using very general strings like `1`

Comment: hello sir can i send you the eps file and the latex code so that you can compile and have a look on that thanks in advance